# Set TextView text from a different Activity(with a different layout)

Tags: java, android

Been struggling with this for a while now. Whenever I try to set the text of a label from my MainActivity using the setText() method, nothing happens, I've tried several solutions none of them seem to work for me,
it is important to know though, that the layout Im trying to change has no Activity, because I want to use it inside another layout which would have a ListView inside, anyway I just wanna know if it is possible for me to do this from my MainActivity, here is an example of what I'm trying to do

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void letsee(View view) {

//LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View content = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test, null);

    //View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView)content.findViewById(R.id.testview);

    tv.setText("DOES THIS EVEN WORK?");

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
}
}
```

this is what I've tested, even what's commented, I want the text to be displayed in the TextView when i click the button to change to testlayout, layout's name's test btw

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rtest">


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/testview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

I am aware you cannot call a resource by its id unless your set layout contains said element, I just hope there is a workaround for that.

Comment: can you use a fragment, bind the fragment to the activity and attach the view to that fragment? or does it have to be from the activity?

Comment: You need call setContentView first

Comment: @paul_hundal sorry man I'm not quite sure what a fragment is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `TextView` without setting `test` layout as content view. Try to set content view first `setContentView(R.layout.test)` then use view as per your needs.

**Try this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                letsee();
            }
        });
    }

    public void letsee() {
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testview);
        tv.setText("DOES THIS EVEN WORK?");
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

You can use `Fragment` to change your view. Here is an complete example:

1. In our MainActivity, there are two buttons named `Fragment No.1` & `Fragment No.2` and a initial `Fragment` named `Fragmentone`
2. If Button `Fragment No.2` pressed, `FragmentOne` will be replaced by `FragmentTwo` (which contains `TextView` value `This is fragment No.2`)
3. If Button `Fragment No.1` pressed, `FragmentTwo` will be replaced by `FragmentOne` (which contains `TextView` value `This is fragment No.1`)

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment No.1"
        android:onClick="selectFrag" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="selectFrag"
         android:text="Fragment No.2" /> 

   <fragment
        android:name="com.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#00ffff">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="This is fragment No.1"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#ffff00">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="This is fragment No.2"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
package com.android.fragmentstest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //Inflate the layout for this fragment

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
   }
}
```

**FragmentTwo.java**

```
package com.android.fragmentstest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // Inflate the layout for this fragment

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
   }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.fragmentstest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
         Fragment fr;

         if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
             fr = new FragmentTwo();

         }else {
             fr = new FragmentOne();
         }

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

You can also see this [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)

Hope this will help~

Comment: This does work, it isn't what i was looking for, but it works. Kinda saw it coming since you set the contentview first. Thanks alot.

Comment: @SoulBlack See my updated answer. I think this exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: After checking your updated answer, I've been thinking about all the possible things i can apply with this new fragment concept (it is new to me at least), anyway thanks for the help man, THATS the right answer

Comment: @SoulBlack My pleasure :)